# rubyで括弧を使うのはやはり邪道ですか？

Tags: ruby

書籍にもとづき基本的な内容を勉強中です。pythonからはじめたのでなにかと括弧を使いたくなります。しかし、進んでいく途中で括弧を使用するとうまく機能しないものもなかにはありますね。

#### Ruby

```
print("hello")
print "hello"
```

#### Ruby失敗例

```
FileUtils.cp %w[test.txt test2.txt], "d1/d2" # => 〇
FileUtils.cp(%w[test.txt test2.txt]), "d1/d2"# => NG
```

rubyメソッドで括弧を使うのはありえないですか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

単純に括弧を付ける位置が間違っているだけです。

```
FileUtils.cp(%w[test.txt test2.txt], "d1/d2")
```